# How i can do this with lua? (preg_match() in php)

Tags: lua

I need help with preg_match in lua, I have tried some different ways.

I tried with `string.match` and `string.find`, but I can't write the pattern correctly.

I know this way in php, but need similar way in lua

```php
$s = "/testas [51]";
preg_match("#/testas [(.*)]#", $s, $out);
print_r($out);
```

I want to get an integer in `[ ]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write this regular expression in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192137/how-to-write-this-regular-expression-in-lua)

Answer (score 0):

To get the integer inside [ ], try this code:

```
print(string.match(s,"/testas%s+%[(%d+)%]"))
```

The pattern comes directly from the specification of the task. We just need to escape the brackets.

Comment: yes, but im need /testas together, checking logs ant if bot will find /testas [int] he just will get 88