# The regex in string.format of LUA

Tags: regex, lua

I use string.format(str, regex) of LUA to fetch some key word.

```
local RICH_TAGS = {
    "texture",
    "img",
}
--\[((img)|(texture))=
local START_OF_PATTER = "\\[("
for index = 1, #RICH_TAGS - 1 do
    START_OF_PATTER = START_OF_PATTER .. "(" .. RICH_TAGS[index]..")|"
end
START_OF_PATTER = START_OF_PATTER .. "("..RICH_TAGS[#RICH_TAGS].."))"

function RichTextDecoder.decodeRich(str)
    local result = {}
    print(str, START_OF_PATTER)
    dump({string.find(str, START_OF_PATTER)})
end
```

output

```
hello[img=123]  \[((texture)|(img)) 
dump from: [string "utils/RichTextDecoder.lua"]:21: in function 'decodeRich'    
"<var>" = { 
}
```

The output means:

str = hello[img=123]

START_OF_PATTER = \[((texture)|(img))

This regex works well with some online regex tools. But it find nothing in LUA.
Is there any wrong using in my code?

Comment: Lua doesn't use `regex` it uses `patterns`. https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use regular expressions in Lua. Use Lua's [string patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) to match strings.

See [How to write this regular expression in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192137/how-to-write-this-regular-expression-in-lua/6192354)

Try `dump({str:find("\\%[%("))})`

Also note that this loop:

```
for index = 1, #RICH_TAGS - 1 do
    START_OF_PATTER = START_OF_PATTER .. "(" .. RICH_TAGS[index]..")|"
end
```

will leave out the last element of `RICH_TAGS`, I assume that was not your intention.

#### Edit:

> But what I want is to fetch several specific word. For example, the
> pattern can fetch "[img=" "[texture=" "[font=" any one of them. With
> the regex string I wrote in my question, regex can do the work. But
> with Lua, the way to do the job is write code like string.find(str,
> "[img=") and string.find(str, "[texture=") and string.find(str,
> "[font="). I wonder there should be a way to do the job with a single
> pattern string. I tryed pattern string like "%[%a*=", but obviously it
> will fetch a lot more string I need.

You cannot match several specific words with a single pattern unless they are in that string in a specific order. The only thing you could do is to put all the characters that make up those words into a class, but then you risk to find any word you can build from those letters.

Usually you would match each word with a separate pattern or you match any word and check if the match is one of your words using a look up table for example.

So basically you do what a regex library would do in a few lines of Lua.

Comment: Does it mean I can't fetch some specific words in Lua?

Comment: of course you can. Luas string matching is just not as powerful as a complete regex library. it was sufficient for all my needs so far. please read my answer again.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't figure out the pattern string. Those character class is useful but I don't know to represent a specific word with them. Would you mind show me the pattern string to fetch  2 specific words like "hello" and "world". With the example, maybe I can understand the answer and figure out solutions.

Comment: if you want to match a specific word you just write the word as is. `"hello"` will match `"hello"`  if you want to find `\[(texture)|` you use `"\\%[%(texture%)|"`. The manual says: **x**: (where **x** is not one of the magic characters ^$()%.[]*+-?) represents the character **x** itself.

Comment: I know the way to fetch a specific word. But what I want is to fetch several specific word. For example, the pattern can fetch "[img=" "[texture=" "[font=" any one of them. With the regex string I wrote in my question, regex can do the work. But with Lua, the way to do the job is write code like         string.find(str, "[img=") and string.find(str, "[texture=") and string.find(str, "[font="). I wonder there should be a way to do the job with a single pattern string. I tryed pattern string like "%[%a*=", but obviously it will fetch a lot more string I need.

Comment: Got it and thanks. That's my current way to fulfill my requirement.